# Bash completion extra words Fedora 23

Tags: bash, fedora, autocomplete

Today I noticed some extra words when TAB completing dnf search.

Anyone has any idea what is causing this behaviour? Tried to dnf clean all and then reinstall bash_completion and dnf update. It didn't work. I have added some aliases and custom bash prompt (PS1) to .bashrc, rest is default.

```
#dnf searc
a              DNF            is             Please         the
and            documentation  not            'plugins'      The
API            function       of             release.       upcoming
at             functions.     officially     removed        use
available      api.html.      only           search         will
be             in             part           supported
```

Comment: THis looks like a bug in bash completion in `dnf` (not the first one and not the last one). Let's see what I can find out.

Comment: Edited my answer. This is already fixed upstream so only thing needed is to wait for distribution to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in bash completion in `dnf` (not the first one and not the last one). Let's see what I can find out.

Running the same with `set -x` will reveal the source of this:

```
 python3 -c 'import sys; from dnf.cli import completion_helper as ch; ch.main(sys.argv[1:])' _cmds sear -d 0 -q -C
```

does not return the list of options, but basically some error. It is because the `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnf/cli/completion_helper.py` is using not-supported API and when debugging, we see errors like this:

> The 'plugins' function is not a part of DNF API and will be removed in the upcoming DNF release. Please use only officially supported API functions. DNF API documentation is available at https://dnf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html.

from line

```
172             base.plugins.load(base.conf.pluginpath, [])
```

This should be `base.init_plugins()` and it was already fixed in the [recent commit](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/commit/ec09be4f734616cc7f33bbace6a8b7a2fed1d2bc). Only thing needed now is to wait until it get fixed in distribution.